# why does location.reload() break my $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element, that posts (just fine) when changed using $.post. But if I want to reload the page, and add a `location.reload()` then it doesn't post. If I remove the line, it posts fine. Any ideas?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#target').change(function() {
            $.post('<?=$base_url?>orders/create-new/order-items/<?=$order_id?>/target', 
              { 
                use_sort_modifier: $('select#target').val(),
                order_id: <?=$order_id?>
              } 
            );
            location.reload(); // Works without this line.
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: you should write this line in the success callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous. Your reload fires before the post has had a chance to finish.

Do the reload in the post's `success` event handler:

```
$.post('<?=$base_url?>orders/create-new/order-items/<?=$order_id?>/target', 
  { 
   use_sort_modifier: $('select#target').val(),
   order_id: <?=$order_id?>
  },
 function() { location.reload(); }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

[`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) executes asynchronously, so it isn't really done when you call `location.reload()`, hence it gets interrupted - you can pass a success callback to `$.post()` that executes once the post has been successfully completed and execute your reload there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do location.reload() on the callback from the post, not just after the post code.

Here is an example:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function() { location.reload() },
      dataType: dataType
    });
```

You need to put it in the `success:` part in your `$post` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a `async: false` into your ajax statement

Comment: Thanks. I am using .post though instead of .ajax.